# BASH label for IP addresses

Tags: bash, label

My fault: I have been so busy learning other linux stuff that I completely neglected the power of bash.

I have a number of systems to access remotely for very simple operations. The problem is that I need to remember each single IP address. And they are a lot.

Using aliases in ~./bashrc is an option:

```
 alias ssh_customer1='ssh root@10.X.X.X'
 alias ssh_customer2='ssh root@10.X.X.Y'
 alias copy_customer1='scp * root@10.X.X.X:/etc/example/'
 alias copy_customer2='scp * root@10.X.X.Y:/etc/example/'
 alias get_customer1='scp root@10.X.X.X:/etc/example/* .'
 alias get_customer2='scp root@10.X.X.Y:/etc/example/* .'
```

but the flexibility is minimal.

Another possibility is to define functions using the name of system as a parameter but I don't like this:

```
sshx('customer1')
scpx('customer2')
```

I would prefer to just replace a label with the corresponding IP address without the need to remember it, and use standard commands:

```
ssh root@ip_customer1
scp root@ip_customer2:/etc/example/* .
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can declare the IP with their nickname with `/etc/hosts`. Another way would be to configure your DNS server and DHCP client/server such that each host advertise its name.

Comment: Yeah just put them in your host file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup a [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host cust1
    HostName 10.X.X.X
    User root
Host cust2
    HostName 10.X.X.Y
    User root
```

Now you can use:

```
ssh cust1
```

Another cool thing is that you can now attach identity files to each server:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host cust1
    HostName 10.X.X.X
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cust1.id_rsa
Host cust2
    HostName 10.X.X.Y
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cust2.id_rsa
```

This will let you use ssh and scp without password, assuming the key is without password or ssh-agent is used.

Comment: Thank you @andIrc, I didn't know of this possibility!
Very well explained.

Comment: @Alex I'm happy that I could help. If you consider using identity files you should also consider running ssh-agent as it will make it possible to have passwords on your identity files without having to retype it every time they are used. :-)

Comment: Brilliant ! +1 for that `IdentityFile` stuff.